# Android application must not run on rooted devices

Tags: android, security, root

I'm writing an application that must not run on rooted devices. I want to store some secure data and which is possible only on non-rooted devices as nobody can access files in */data/data/package-name*.

Does anyone know:

**1)** Is it possible to prevent the installation of an application on rooted devices? I read something about the "copy-protection mechanism" of Android Market. This feature seems to be outdated and replaced by the licensing feature. However, licensing is only possible for paid application and mine is free...

**2)** Is it possible to check programmatically whether a device is rooted or not? If it would be possible to do so I could simply stop the application if the device is rooted.

Any help regarding this topic is appreciated!

Comment: The market says it will be deprecated soon, but it's not yet, if you get no other solutions, you can use it for now.

Comment: This is many shades of not possible.

Answer (score 9):

Execute

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

and check the result code.

In other words, if you can exec `su`, then you have root access. it doesn't matter if the user allows or denies it, you have your answer.

Comment: That sounds like a really good idea, but unfortunately, the method exec() is undefined for the type Runtime...
The only method that seems to exist on Android is "getInstanceCount"...

Comment: Runtime.exec() is defined, i've used it. see: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html

Comment: This likely won't work. When you ask for root, the use can simply deny it to your app and you'll be none the wiser.  If they grant it and you tell them "Hehehe you can't use my app on a rooted device" they will just go "fine, no root for you" and you'll be none the wiser again.

Comment: Which is the reason why it's kinda dumb to write a "no rooted device" app.  Root access is governed by the user itself, which almost as secure as governing it by the service provider.  Security is about being smart and making logical choices, not about SW or HW.

Comment: @BrendanByrd on a rooted device, there is no way to secure sensitive data from other apps, and it's trivial for another app to get access to another apps' data that is otherwise private and secure. in other words, the entire sandbox model is compromised. there are many situations where that cannot be allowed.

Comment: @John simply follow up by requesting a protected operation ... reading a protected file, or whatever, if it fails, you know you've been denied.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman You're missing the point.  Even if the device is rooted the user has to grant YOUR app access to root.  If the user of a rooted device denies your app access to root you'll read your protected file and will be denied.  Then the user will turn around and go to their rooted file browser and read whatever they want and you won't have a clue.

Comment: Process P = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); works for me. This is a comment to the answer, not the conversation at hand.

Comment: i think what @Steven_BDawg is saying is that the simple fact that you can exec `su` means you are rooted. the user can deny it or accept it, it doesn't matter, you have your answer.

Answer (score 6):

I think your approach is a bit flawed. First of all, the user can first install your application and data, then "root" the device (even if rooting wipes the data, one can make the backup first). Next, the general rule is that whatever is in user's hands is not yours anymore. The hacker will find a way to get to your data sooner or later.

If you care about secure data, don't put it to device. As Android is net-centric device (yes, I know, that's subjective, but it was initially developed and positioned as such), accessing the data online is not uncommon.

Comment: Not to mention having root means you'll likely be able to bypass most security measures anyway.

Comment: Thats the reason why I'm looking for a way that the app is not installed on rooted devices...

Comment: @Peter: Kind of a circular argument here. What I mean by that is that any security measure you put in place to avoid installing it on a rooted devices can likely be bypassed by having root privileges.

Comment: @kcoppock: Ok, now I got your point :-) I think using runtime.exec("su") would help a lot. Checking on every start of the app whether the device is rooted sounds reasonable to me. Even if the device has been rooted meanwhile root still cannot change the source code of the app to disable the check... Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Peter: I'm no hacker, but really, anything that can be locked, can be unlocked. I would imagine the Runtime.exec() function could be modified to always return a value that would lead your app to believe the device is not rooted. The copy protection you listed in the original question is easy to bypass with a rooted phone. When I first upgraded my Droid to a custom ROM of Froyo, a lot of the apps I had previously purchased wouldn't show up in Market because some ID didn't match up properly. Just took modifying a single file (build.prop, I believe?) to trick it to think I was running Eclair.

Comment: Really, it's as Zer said, is it worth the time to crack it? If it is, then someone definitely will, regardless of what security you implement. Doesn't mean you shouldn't use security (like locking your car door, if someone wants in they can break a window), but if it's more difficult to crack than it's worth to spend the time cracking, it's likely good enough. Then again, IANASE (security expert :P )

Comment: @Peter if somebody roots the device, he can get your code and your data and analyze them on desktop (including extraction of encryption key) without running your application.

Answer (score 4):

What I would say is to run `su` and then check the output. If the user allows your app to have root, then use root to uninstall your own application (one way might be to place a script into `init.d` and then force a reboot).

If the user **DOES NOT** allow your app to run as root, then:

1. They **DENIED** your app permissions.
2. They are not rooted.

Now, denying permissions (and rooted) means that they have some sort of SUPERUSER management app, and that's where this next part comes in.

I would then proceed to use `PackageManager` to retrieve a list of all packages and then check them against the handful SuperUser management apps available, namely the ones by Koush, ChainsDD, and Chainfire

The relevant package names are:

1. `com.noshufou.android.su`
2. `eu.chainfire.supersu`
3. `com.koushikdutta.superuser`

Answer (score 4):

Use those methods which will help you check for root

```
public static boolean findBinary(String binaryName) {
        boolean found = false;
        if (!found) {
            String[] places = { "/sbin/", "/system/bin/", "/system/xbin/",
                    "/data/local/xbin/", "/data/local/bin/",
                    "/system/sd/xbin/", "/system/bin/failsafe/", "/data/local/" };
            for (String where : places) {
                if (new File(where + binaryName).exists()) {
                    found = true;

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return found;
    }

    private static boolean isRooted() {
        return findBinary("su");
    }
```

Now try to check whether the device is rooted.

```
if (isRooted() == true){
//Do something to prevent run this app on the device

}
else{
//Do nothing and run app normally
}
```

For example you can force stop the app if the device is rooted

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to protect data *for* the user, it's their business to worry about other apps.
If you are trying to protect data *from* the user, what business do you have putting it on their device?

To answer your question, they are in control of the machine so expect them to be able to trap any call to an API checking 'Is this rooted?' and lie to you. Instead, encrypt the data on the client with a key known to the client, but make it non-obvious where and how you are doing it. Generally make things annoying for whoever is looking.

Enjoy the ensuing game of whack-a-mole. Every time someone cracks into it, you'll make a better fix, they'll make a better crack, and all along the way *you will be raising the barrier for cracking it*.

Don't fight against freedom - why should you turn away customers with free devices anyway? - instead, if you want a particular outcome, make it so Bother To Get Data > Value Of Getting Data. Then it won't happen. If you truly *must* have fool-proof security, keep the data server-side.

Comment: Actually, I'm creating a keypair (public & private) on the device and want to store it in an own keystore. The password for accessing this keystore should be stored as safe as possible so that even on a rooted phone, no one in the possession of the phone can get the private key...

Comment: You are storing the password for accessing the key along with the key? Awfully insecure don't you think? .. Why not just encrypt the keypair with a passphrase, so that it will only decrypt correctly if they enter the right one? It's what SSH and friends do..

Comment: If you are trying to protect data for the user, it's their business to worry about other apps. no offense, that's a naive approach to security. by that logic, my browser should just store all of my password in a plain text file in c:/passwords.txt, right? after all, it's the user's problem if they happen to install malicious app.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that one of the 'drawbacks' of the traditional copy protection was that it did not allow the application to be installed on rooted devices, but it also has its own share of problems and will be deprecated soon.

As for client-side checks, you simply cannot rely on a programmatic approach to detect if you're running on a rooted device or not -- anything that is in client-side code can and will be hacked and removed. You'd be surprised at how easy it is to modify even Proguard-obfuscated code. At best, you force the hacker to spend a few hours or days to edit the code and recompile. This is security through obscurity, and not a viable protection mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

1) no. how would you deny installation? why would a rooted device deny installation of something the user wants to install on the fs? being the whole point of rooting that you can make the device do basically whatever.

2) no. not for your purposes. you can check if you can gain root for your application through the usual methods. so you can make a check for a positive but you cannot prove programmatically that it is not rooted, from within your app.

also, what you are asking if you can make perfect copy protection drm system - you might also be missing the point that the user can alter your application, removing your root check. if you have a checksum/crc check of some kind, the user can fake the result of that as well.